# How do i get the function to restart with new values after the user answer Yes when asked if he wants to try again?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, while-loop

**UPDATED** - I am trying to get the score updated after every run of the game so basically when the user or computer wins, the score should be updated, but it only updates it once. How do i get the userwin and compwin to stay updated after a new try?

**SOLVED **I need the to get the computer choice to reset after the end of the game and it has to be in the REPLAY function.
The code only restarts the function without getting new values.

```
import random

def retry():
    while True:
        replay = input("Want to try again?").lower()
        if replay not in "yn":
            print("Please enter Yes or No.")
        elif replay == "n" or replay == 'no':
            print("Thanks for playing.\n Bye now!")
            break
        elif replay == "y" or replay == "yes":
            print("Let's try again!")
            return rps()

def rps():
    while True:
        compwin = 0
        userwin = 0
        computer = random.choice(picks)
        user = input("Choose: Rock, Paper, Scissors: \n").lower()
        if user not in ['rock','paper','scissors']:
            print("Please choose a valid option.")
        if user == computer:
            print("It's a draw.")
            return retry()
        if ((user == 'rock' and computer == 'paper')or
            (user == 'paper' and computer == 'scissors')or
            (user == 'scissors' and computer == 'rock')):
                print("Computer won")
                compwin += 1
                print("Computer won: ",compwin,"games")
                return retry()
        if ((user == 'scissors' and computer == 'paper')or
              (user == 'paper' and computer == 'rock')or
              (user == 'rock' and computer == 'scissors')):
                print('You won!')
                userwin += 1
                print("User won: ",userwin,"games")
                return retry()


#Pay attention to wording and parantheses and where you add the line of codes: choice/choices()
picks = (['rock','paper','scissors'])
rps()
```

Comment: your `computer` variable is not inside a function/loop and only gets triggered once, hence you're not seeing any change. You can fix it with restructuring that line.

Comment: @Clueless_captain I have tried before and again now and it keeps giving me this error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'computer' referenced before assignment.
And I have to reference it in the functions but it won t work because of the error

Comment: @Clueless_captain I got it. I have to pay more attention to where i place the lines of code. I ve put the computer = random.choice(choice) at the beginning of the code and it works just fine. Thanks

Comment: Great! One thing I'd try to avoid is using `choice` as a variable name for your list of options as `choice` is also the name of a method in `random`. I've always learned that as a best-practice.

Comment: @Clueless_captain summoning you again. Can you please check the updated question?

Comment: Okay, you're facing the same kind of error as with your initial question. Your variables `compwin` and `userwin` are local variables beloging to the function `rps`. Each time you call them, these get set to `0`. You call them each time after answering 'yes' on the retry loop. 

There are a few ways to fix it. The easiest is to put `compwin` and `userwin` outside the two functions and use them as a `global`. You instantiate them once on launching the script and re-use them in `rps` by fetching them from the global scope by writing `global userwin` and `global compwin`